# About the system calls when writing a simple shell

Tags: c, shell, unix

I have an assignment which is about writing a simple Unix shell.

My teacher says that I need to "check the return value of EVERY system call". Below is how I understand the meaning of "check the return value of EVERY system call".

So for example, if there is this line in my code:

```
int returnValue = kill (9999, SIGINT); 
/* 9999 is the pid of some process */
```

As you already know, kill() returns 0 for a successful call and -1 if an error occurs.
So if returnValue is actually "-1" then I should print out some error message.

Do I understand the meaning of "check the return value of EVERY system call" correctly? I don't really think so because the assignment description just says about checking the return value of system calls but it doesn't say anything about the format of error message or what I should do when some error occurs in a system call. Can anyone please give me some ideas ?

Comment: You should probably ask the teacher... What exactly they expect you to do is up to them. But of course you can use common sense. Such as, if opening a file fails, there's no point trying to read from it. If creating a child process fails, there's no point in waiting for it to exit. Etc. In simple programs the only sensible option is often to print the error (exact error number/message, as well as context such as file name, and the system call that failed) and exit.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea. If a system call fails, you don't want it to just go by silently. The decision you need to make is whether the error is serious enough to exit your own program, or whether your own program can meaningfully continue (whether by retrying the system call; taking some other action, which could be simply printing an error message; or ignoring it).